# Difference in utf8 (greek) characters output in codeigniter, standard html vs form helper

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encoding, codeigniter-form-helper

This:

```
<td><?php echo form_input('post_title',set_value('post_title',$post->post_title)); ?></td>
```

Will present greek characters (or any other than latin character), as &#xxx on the page.

This:

```
<p>Title: <input name="post_title" type="text" value="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>"/></p>
```

Will display it correctly.

[image: Web page]

My MySQL type is MyISAM and utf8_latin_ci collation.

Trying browse from phpMyAdmin also gives me greek in &#xxx...

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Where is the mistake?

P.S From codeigniter manual regarding the form helper methods

> and will always add the attribute accept-charset based on the charset
>   value in your config file.

My config file is set to

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

UPDATE: My page headers:

```
GET /posts/editpost/23 HTTP/1.1
Host: my.xxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
Referer: http://my.xxx.com/posts
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general issue with the characters set. Please keep the character set encoding same at every place like in HTML files, CI config file and most important at the database. While creating a database, select UTF-8 or any other other which suits to your language (for most languages UTF-8 works). Or you can change it for individual tables also. Please make these changes and you will get the correct one for greek language. 
Thank you

Comment: Although i understand the generality of this, i cant understand why on the same page i can see the characters with std HTML and i cant see them if i use CI commands. I will update my first post with my page headers.

Comment: @e4rthdog `&xxx;` is html specific (to encode any character in ASCII, but it only works in HTML context) and completely useless if you are using UTF-8 as UTF-8 supports these characters as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with these three Text helper functions:

```
ascii_to_entities()
```

or

```
entities_to_ascii()
```

or

```
convert_accented_characters()
```

depends how you have saved it in your database

They are from CI's  **Text helper**:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html

and **don't forget to load this helper too** ;)